# how to extract lower bytes from a Hex value?

Tags: c, hex, byte, extract

I am making a program to communicate with a serial device. Device is giving me the data in hex format. Hex format which I am getting is `FFFFFF84` but I am interested in extracting the last two bits that is `84` . So how can i extract it?

```
while(1)
{
int i;
char receivebuffer [1];
read (fd, receivebuffer, sizeof receivebuffer);  
for ( i = 0; i < sizeof (receivebuffer); i++)
{
   printf("value of buffer is %X\n\n", (char)receivebuffer[i]);

}
return 0;
}
```

I am getting the data in receivebuffer. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you want to extract the last 2 byte? you need operator '&' extract it:

```
FFFFFF84 -> 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0100
000000FF -> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
---------------------------------------------------
after &  -> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0100
```

so the anwser is do assignment:

```
last2 = input & 0xFF
```

hope this anwser help you understand bit operation.

Answer (score 1):

You're just confused because `printf` is printing your data as a sign-extended `int` (this means that `char` on your system `char` is treated as signed - note that this is implementation-defined).

Change your `printf` to:

```
printf("value of buffer is %#X\n\n", (unsigned char)receivebuffer[i]);
```

or just make the type of `receivebuffer` unsigned:

```
unsigned char receivebuffer[1];

// ...

printf("value of buffer is %#X\n\n", receivebuffer[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Device is giving me the data in hex format.

This contradicts your code. It seems the device gives you the data in binary (raw) format and you covert it to hex for printing. That is a huge difference.

If you do

```
printf("value of buffer is %X\n\n", (char)receivebuffer[i]);
```

the `char` (whose cast is unnecessary as it is already a `char`) gets converted to `int`. As your system has `char` signed, the resulting `int` is negative and thus the `FFF...` at the start.

You can do any of

```
printf("value of buffer is %X\n\n", receivebuffer[i] & 0xFF);
printf("value of buffer is %X\n\n", (unsigned char)receivebuffer[i]);
printf("value of buffer is %X\n\n", (uint8_t)receivebuffer[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic but I just want to add another option:

```
printf("value of buffer is %hhx\n\n", receivebuffer[i]);
```

`%hhx` translates to a "short short hex" value, or in other words, an 8-bit hex value.

Answer (score 0):

The device just returns bytes. It is the `printf` which displays a byte in a certain format (decimal, hex, etc.). To show bytes in hex you should use "0x%02x" format.